# Load JS Script only for custom post types

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I am using this code and I am not sure why the script is not loaded. I believe the syntax is correct since I am trying to load the script only on the "events" custom post type single posts.

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_login_enqueue_scripts', 10 );
function wpse_login_enqueue_scripts() {
    if( is_single() && get_post_type()=='events' ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enqueue scripts on the front-end, the hook should be `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `login_enqueue_scripts`.

Also, a better way to see if you’re on a single custom post type is to use `is_singular()` and pass the post type you want to check:

```
if ( is_singular( 'events' ) ) {
}
```

`get_post_type()` relies on the global `$post` object, and not the main query. They're often the same but under some circumstances the `$post` object might not be the same post as the current single post.

Comment: ah, nice catch -- edit -- though this is a more elegant solution, to be 100% accurate it should be noted that `is_single()` does return true for all post types (`any post type, except attachments and pages`, see: [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) )

Comment: great, and I thought I was doing everything right lol

Comment: @Iceable You're right. Amending my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this hook is only fired on the login page :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/

to use on a custom post page, use the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking this function to `'login_enqueue_scripts'` (which only runs on the login page) ; you sould hook it to `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` instead.

Also `( is_single() && get_post_type()=='events' )` would work, but as Jacob Peattie pointed out in another answer, `is_singular( 'events' )` is the best way to check for a custom post type single post.

Lastly you should rename the function from `wpse_login_enqueue_scripts()` to something like `wpse_events_enqueue_scripts()` to make it more descriptive and less confusing:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_events_enqueue_scripts', 10 );
function wpse_events_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( is_single() && 'events' == get_post_type() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
    }
}
```